# Why is 0x10001 used as an RSA exponent so often?

Tags: rsa

Are there any other commonly used exponents? Why are they selected?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. Here's a link to an interesting question at Information Security answered by Thomas Pornin years ago : [Should RSA public exponent be only in {3, 5, 17, 257 or 65537} due to security considerations?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/2335/86735)

Comment: Related [RSA public key exponent generation confusion](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22437/18298), [Statistics on the frequency of usage of RSA key public exponents](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/52581/18298) [Impacts of not using RSA exponent of 65537](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3113/18298)

Comment: Another common one is 37, see [Why is PuTTYgen-created RSA public exponent(e) not in {3,17,65537}?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/30823/555)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want a number co-prime with p-1 and q-1.
We also want modular exponentiation tp be efficient. For this purpose we want it to be a small number with few set bits.
To meet the co-prime requirement we can pick a prime number and verify and we are reasonably likely to succeed.

For all these together we are looking at small primes of the form: $2^n+1$ known as Fermat primes. These numbers leads to efficient public key operations.

Using 3 is an obvious choice but some don't like it, partly due to real attacks when not padding and partly irrational fear. slightly larger such primes became popular.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the beginning of that [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/should-rsa-public-exponent-be-only-in-3-5-17-257-or-65537-due-to-security-c) from info security stackexchange for the reader’s convenience:

> There is no known weakness for any short or long public exponent for RSA, as long as the public exponent is "correct" (i.e. relatively prime to p-1 for all primes p which divide the modulus).
>
> If you use a small exponent and you do not use any padding for encryption and you encrypt the exact same message with several distinct public keys, then your message is at risk: if $e = 3,$ and you encrypt message $m$ with public keys $n_1,n_2,n_3$ then you have $c_i= m^3 \pmod{n_i}$ and use the chinese remainder theorem to recover the message by a
>   non modular cube root extraction.
>
> The weakness, here, is not the small exponent; rather, it is the use of an improper padding (namely, no padding at all) for encryption.